# How to write an EF Core outer join that returns objects that contain subarrays?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, ef-core-3.1

I am attempting to do a left outer join in Linq to Sql in order to include all roles for a given user:

```
from au
    in Db.AspNetApplicationUsers
where au.ApplicationId == applicationId
join u in Db.AspNetUsers 
    on au.UserId equals u.Id
join r in Db.AspNetUserRoles 
    on au.UserId equals r.UserId 
    into ur
from userRole in ur.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new UserSummary
{
    Active = au.Active,
    Email = u.NormalizedEmail,
    Name = u.FullName,
    Id = u.Id,
    LastLogin = u.LastLogin,
    LastPasswordChange = u.PasswordLastChanged,
    LockedOut = u.LockoutEnabled,
    Roles = (from x in ur where userRole.RoleId != null select userRole.RoleId).ToArray()
}
```

but receive the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type.'
```

I don't use outer joins in EF often, so I'm sure I'm just messing up the syntax.

Is it possible to return an array to a property in Linq to SQL?

If I add the `where userRole.RoleId != null` condition after `from userRole in ur.DefaultIfEmpty()` the code doesn't fail there anymore, but does during serialization.  I've disabled lazy loading so that's interesting.

Comment: All those manual joins... why aren't you using navigation properties? Also, LinQ to SQL != Entity Framework, different products, the first one being considered deprecated.

Comment: I believe you should first assign the `RoleId` in `anonymous` object using `userRole.RoleId` and over the formed collection use GroupBy to create `UserSummary` to get Roles as collection.

Comment: Also, that data structure is remarkably similar to ASP.NET Core Identity's. If so, just `Roles = user.UserRoles.Where(r => r.RoleId != null).Select(r => r.RoleId).ToArray()`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - Yeah, I stink with names.  Can't remember my own half the time.  :)  Was doing the joins to make sure the data is included in the output and not set to null.  Dislike working with black boxes, hard to tell what it's smart enough to do.  If I don't use the join and just select the list of Users, that data is not populated in the results.  However your code above included that data, and worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked! When it comes to EF, it's always a black box; your best friends are tools like SQL Server Profiler when you have to analyze queries. But, with EF Core 3.x, you should be good in most simple scenarios like this one :) Notice that you could likely remove all joins in this question and use navigational properties and still have the same SQL query generated

Answer (score 1):

As per CamiloTerevinto's suggestion, the following worked just fine:

```
from au
    in Db.AspNetApplicationUsers
where au.ApplicationId == applicationId
select new UserSummary
{
    Active = au.Active,
    Email = au.User.NormalizedEmail,
    Name = au.User.FullName,
    Id = au.User.Id,
    LastLogin = au.User.LastLogin,
    LastPasswordChange = au.User.PasswordLastChanged,
    LockedOut = au.User.LockoutEnabled,
    Roles = au.User.AspNetUserRoles.Where(r => r.RoleId != null).Select(r => r.RoleId).ToArray()
}
```